# How can I download Audible Books to Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, compatibility, audiobook, audible

I use Ubuntu, and currently I have version 9.04 installed. I would like to try the Audible (http://www.audible.com) audio book seller, but I can't figure out how to download the audio files to my machine - when I try, I get a file titled **aw_dhelper.pl** with contents like:

```
user_id=myaccount&product_id=BK_BUZZ_000005b&order_number=AUD055555555555&
agg_id=&awtype=&title=SummerKnightUnabridgedPart2&
assemble_url=http://cdl.audible.com/cgi-bin/aw_assemble_title.pl&
cleanup_url=http://cdl.audible.com/cgi-bin/aw_cleanup_title.pl&
size=234567&DownloadType=Now&domain=www.audible.com&codec=mp332&
transfer_player=1&browser_type=
```

I have tried to install AudibleManager under Crossover Linux, but so far it is not working.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cheated and installed on a virtual machine running windows as a guest. This was partly because I wanted to export the audio files to CD to play in my car.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the mentioned blog post, [Audible on Ubuntu](http://phpmn.blogspot.com/2008/06/audible-on-ubuntu.html), I was able to download the Audible files with the following command:

```
$ "/home/eric/.cxoffice/Audible/desktopdata/cxmenu/
StartMenu.C^5E3A^5Fusers^5FPublic^5FStart^2BMenu/Programs/
AudibleManager/Audible+Download+Manager" aw_dhelper.pl
```

To break it down, the first part, **/home/.../AudibleManager/** is the path to the Audible provide application "Audible Download Manager". I am using Crossover Linux, so the path to the utility is as shown. If one is using WINE instead of Crossover Linux, the Windows binary would be called differently.

The second part, **aw-dhelper.pl** is the small file I downloaded from Audible.com. No matter what file you try to download, the output from the browser is **aw-dhelper.pl**.

The only mechanism Audible Download Manager provides for opening the required **aw-dhelper.pl** file is as a command line argument. One must either manually call the utility from the command line, figure out how to get firefox to call a WINE or Crossover Linux application, or write a shell script and have Firefox "open" file with the shell script (it is the solution provided in the referenced blog post, [Audible on Ubuntu](http://phpmn.blogspot.com/2008/06/audible-on-ubuntu.html))

Unfortunately, the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=933707) technique mentioned by nik did not work. I suspect that Audible has adjusted their scripting. Alternatively, I simply am not configured to use the correct "device"

Answer (score 1):

Look at [**[SOLVED] HOW TO download books from Audible.com**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=933707)

There is also a [WINE+Firefox suggestion on this post](http://phpmn.blogspot.com/2008/06/audible-on-ubuntu.html).

Comment: thanks. Definitely a start. The file format is a little different. I will experiment some more.

Answer (score 1):

if you are reading this because you want to use audible on linux you should shoot an email over to the audible help desk.

http://audible.custhelp.com/app/ask

let them know you want to pay for books but can't download them on your machine. or something like that in your own way